# How to reuse jQuery of target page in userscripts?

Tags: jquery, userscripts

Instead of using `@require` (that is GM specific) or [injecting a <script> element](http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/) (e.g. for pre-0.8 GMs & other browsers), I'd like to use the `jQuery` object that the target page already loads and uses.

Is that kind of situation feasible and how to get it working? I've tried just using the `$` or `jQuery` but it won't work. I've also tried the `GM_wait`-timer-trick mentioned in the linked article, but with no go.

If it isn't going to work, why not?

Answer (score 0):

try using `unsafeWindow.` It gives access to a page's local variables.

for eg:
`$ = unsafeWindow.$`

Answer (score -1):

Try to paste all the jquery code in user javascript file.

Comment: Not exactly qualify as using the page's jQuery object, as required.